# Visual Studio 2019 Preview Intelisense shows red line squiggles but compiles successfully in C# library project with .NET 5

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

My Visual Studio 2019 Preview Intelisense shows red line squiggles but compiles successfully in a C# library project with .NET 5.

[image]

**Info:**

1.Visual studio -> project properties -> Application: Target Frameworks: .NET 5.0

2 CSharp9.csproj ->

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

3 Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 Preview

Version 16.9.0 Preview 2.0

**What  I have tried but failed:**

1 Deleted .vs folder

2 Upgraded to the latest VS 2019

**Update**

1 the red line below public and record: unexpected token

2 the red colour for FirstName: cannot resolve symbol 'FirstName'

Code to replicate

```
public record Person
        {
            public string FirstName { get; }
            public string LastName { get; }
            public Person(string firstName, string lastName) => (FirstName, LastName) = (firstName, lastName);
        }
        public record Teacher : Person
        {
            public string Subject { get; }

            public Teacher(string first, string last, string sub)
                : base(first, last) => Subject = sub;
        }
        public sealed record Student : Person
        {
            public int Level { get; }

            public Student(string first, string last, int level) : base(first, last) => Level = level;
        }
```

Comment: So what does it think the errors are? For each line there should be an entry in the Errors window

Comment: pls see the update at the bottom of my OP.

Comment: It's a review. Bugs are expected and sometimes they may be due to processing delays